# Input.deviceOrientation always Unknown

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I've created a scene with a Canvas with some UI elements. The Canvas has a C# script attached where I check the device orientation.

```
if (Input.deviceOrientation == DeviceOrientation.LandscapeLeft ||
    Input.deviceOrientation == DeviceOrientation.LandscapeRight)
{
    // Do something...
}
```

Everything works fine on my Android device, but when I import the Google Cardboard SDK *(I need to use it in another scene)*, `Input.deviceOrientation` is always `Unknown`.

It seems that the Google Cardboard Plugin for Android prevents the device orientation to be read.

Here's the manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" />
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
                 android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name="com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.plugins.unity.UnityCardboardActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="com.google.intent.category.CARDBOARD" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```